# how to get list of printer trays using cmd

Tags: cmd, printing, wmic, tray

i need to get a list of every available paper tray of a specific printer.

i want to use `cmd` so the script can run on multiple windows PCs without additional software.

i was able to figure out some information using `wmic printer get` but it seems like there is no option for showing available paper trays.